# How to route url sections with more than one segment

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I need to pass a url to different back-ends based on a prefix. For example, the following url

http://mysite/backend1/rest/of/url

needs to be routed to "BackendComponent" with :backend and :restOfUrl tokens where :backend = 'backend1' and :restOfUrl = 'rest/of/url'

I've tried

```
 {
    path: ':backend/:restofurl',
    component: BackendComponent
 }
```

but no route was found. I've also tried simply

```
path: 'Backend1/:restofurl'
```

but it only works if :restofurl has no forward slash (i.e. only one segment)

is this possible in Angular 2+? if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that

```
{
    path: 'Backend1',
    component: BackendComponent,
    children: [
        { path: '**', component: BackendComponent }
    ]
}
```